# How to sanitize input from csv file in Python using re (or a better module?)

Tags: python, csv, validation, sanitization, python-re

My apologies if this is close to a similar question, but I haven't been able to find any useful information on how to sanitize this particular outlier. Hoping someone with more experience can lend a hand.

I have shell script that executes a sql query. All of the data sanitation occurs within the shell script, and the output I'm dealing with in Python for calculations and other things, but there is 1 particular component that is simply apart of the data model (or how the team decided to input it) that I need to clean up in Python. Below is the output:

```
['gnome (assorted', 'untriaged)', 'email', '264131', '1677414', 'CLOSED', '401983', '20817924', '0', '775', '13770692', '2865056', '58683', '19338541', 'release', 'team']
```

The issue here lies within `['gnome (assorted', 'untriaged)']`.
This should actually read `['gnome-assorted-untriaged']` so it could be accessed similar to the following pseudo code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
output.csv = ['gnome (assorted', 'untriaged)', 'email', '264131', '1677414', 'CLOSED', '401983', '20817924', '0', '775', '13770692', '2865056', '58683', '19338541', 'release', 'team']

with open('output.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in reader:
        print(line[0]) # this should return gnome-assorted-untriaged
```

I'm not entirely sure of how to clean this up since it creates 2 indices for what should be one, but I've been trying to utilize Python re module to attempt this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like this problem should be dealt with in the shell script (or the data input), rather than in python. In any case, you will have to check for the pattern that always occurs. For example, see if the first index always contains `(` and the second one always ends with `)` and merge them together. But it could also be the case where this is not always true.

Comment: Thanks @ThuYeinTun. Unfortunately I've already explored that route with awk and sed (which is what I'm currently using in the shell script) and this is constantly the only outlier out of thousands of records. I was hoping someone might know of a simple way to handle this in Python

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a temporary solution below, but if anyone knows how I can make this more universal instead of simply fixing this individual outlier I would greatly appreciate it!

### Original Problem

> The issue here lies within `['gnome (assorted', 'untriaged)']`. This
> should actually read `['gnome-assorted-untriaged']` so that index 0 will access the entire component instead of having two indices

### Solution

I ended up just having to create a conditional for this particular outlier, segregating it and writing the results to a new file. If the conditional for `bad_line` was not met, the line was also written to the new file.

```
def sanitize():

    #todo: Come back and make this more universal instead of fixing the single 
           outlier
    with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
    with open('cleaned_output.csv', 'w')as w:
        reader = csv.reader(f) # reader object for output.csv
        writer = csv.writer(w) # writer object for cleaned_output.csv
        bad_pattern = re.compile(r'\s') # search pattern for a space

        for line in reader:
            bad_line = bad_pattern.search(str(line[0])) # search index 0 for a space in each line. Returns NoneType

            if bad_line != None:
                # the only line that should be here is gnome (assorted, untriaged)
                l0 = re.sub(r'gnome \(assorted', 'gnome-assorted', line[0])
                l1 = re.sub(r'untriaged\)', '-untriaged', line[1])
                fixed_comp = l0 + l1
                line[0] = fixed_comp
                del line[1]
                writer.writerow(line)
            else:
                writer.writerow(line)
```